# Could time consistently flow in reverse?

Tags: spacetime, time

Could time consistently flow in reverse?
[Here](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/royprsa/472/2185/20150670.full.pdf) is an article about the subject of quantum asymmetry of time and space.

Thoughts?

Comment: do not believe everything you read, You are right to question the experts

Comment: Could left/right consistently flow in reverse?

Comment: I am failing to detect the grand idea in the paper. Starting out with a path integral should recover a Schroedinger-like equation... check, but irrelevant. A path integral is basically the integral form of a partial differential equation... the choice of which paths one integrates over might be mathematically equivalent to a violation of time reversal, but it's physically irrelevant unless an actual physical mechanism for that choice is given, which I don't see. A lot of people have, IMHO, made similar observations to hers, but nothing seems to gel into actual physics, so far.

Comment: Interestingly she does cite an observation in 2012, published in Phys Rev Lett of a time reversal violation in a B0 meson system; quite what this means I'm not sure.

Comment: @CuriousOne - so, if she established a correlation between a possible physical mechanism for her path integral, would that convince you of such a possibility (i.e. time reversal might be possible)?

Comment: She is a quantum mystic who works on the level of non-relativistic physics. That's a trivial toy model that has next to nothing to do with the real world. What we are looking for is a quantum theory of spacetime that shows a phase transition at (or near) T_cosmological = 0 and that includes gravity, the cosmological constant and reproduces the entire spectrum of matter. As for time reversal... I don't think you would actually want that. I can't think of a scenario in which it wouldn't instantly kill you.